# Select Max Value in linq to entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to select MAX LevelId value for a **user** and then assign that value to a variable.

In plain SQL the equivalent is:

```
SELECT        MAX(LevelID) AS MaxLevel
FROM            Character
WHERE        (UserId = 'John')


//Check User existing Characters max level per user
```

**int UserLevelID = 0;**

```
var userQuery = (from o in db.Characters
where o.UserId == UserID
      select o);
```

**UserLevelID = userQuery.Max(LevelID);**

Here lies the problem. I don't know how to extract the max value of levelID

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it all in one query:

```
var userLevelId = db.Characters.Where(o => o.UserID == UserID)
                               .Max(o => o.LevelID);
```

I've changed it away from being a query expression because that was introducing more cruft - use query expressions where they actually help readability, and extension method calls for simple solutions where they're more readable.

Comment: How do I assign the value to UserLevelID (variable). Is it just UserLevelID = userQuery

Comment: The problem with this query is that aggregate functions require non-empty sequences... and you have no guarantee that the Where extension method will return a non-empty sequence, so the previous sentence will not work during execution. LinQToEntities provides a "DefaultIfEmpty" extension method that is quite useful for this purpose: Where(...).DefaultIfEmpty(...).Max(...)

Comment: @Luis: If that's the desired behaviour, yes. It's not clear what the OP actually wants in the case of there being no results though. (They seem to be happy enough with this answer...)

Comment: how to post it in view, inside foreach or just call var

Comment: @SAR: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all, but it doesn't seem particularly related to this question...

Comment: @JonSkeet, it ok i found what i needed

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
var theLevel = db.Characters.Where(z => z.UserId == UserID).Max(z => z.LevelID);
```

Answer (score 0):

var max = db.Characters.Where(o => o.UserID == UserID).Max(o => o == null ? 0 : o.LevelID);

when there are no records in db it would return 0 with no exception.